# Convergent Sequence Summation Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. Prove that the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^n}$ converges and $x \in [0, 1]$.

This is a review question I have for a class I need some help with. 
My first attempt at a similar problem bore no decent answer. I was advised that I needed to show the partial sums 
$S_n$ = $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{10^k}$

are increasing and $S_n$ $\leq 1 \forall n$ and then use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

I attempted to pull out $a_n$ and treat it as a fraction, but that' wasn't the correct process to the problem.

If anyone could help provide a start to finish solution I'd be grateful.

Comment: This problem seems fishy. There's a typo on the first line.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Ah, I see it, I'll fix it as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

- To show that it is bounded by $1$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n}$$

Can you evaluate the right hand side?

- You still have to show that it is monotone, which I will leave as an exercise.